# Elasticsearch field is analyzed despite template is configured to not analyze field

Tags: elasticsearch

My logstash template looks like this - https://gist.github.com/gauravarora/5e84f6c95ab83e563502

There are two fields, zone and username that I have set as `not_analyzed` yet they continue to be analyzed and show as analyzed when I view the index mapping. I have dropped the index multiple times in the hopes that it will pick up the new template but the fields are always analyzed.

The index is dynamically created daily so I cannot set the mapping in the index itself.

Is there something wrong with my template?

Edit: I tried this config also - https://gist.github.com/gauravarora/359d71999ed811ae56c6 but doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that I had renamed the index from logstash-* to something-* and the template was only applied to indexes matching logstash-*. Changing the template to match something-* fixed everything.